# UnicodeEncodeError while using aiohttp in python3.6

Tags: encoding, python-asyncio, python-unicode, unicode-string, aiohttp

I use aiohttp to make request to my url, but I don`t know why this error occurs!!!!!

```
async def get_location_data(url):
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                data = await response.json() 
                return data 
    except Exception:
        return None
```

while I get the response and I want to change items of my list, this error happens:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have searched so much about it, some people said that I should use response.text(encoding="utf-8) or response.json(encoding="utf-8)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: stack trace would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other people have said, use `await response.json(encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: I tried again and I found because of some configurations in the server of our company couldn`t get unicode strings from json response. Thanks a lot